# How to use Google Direction API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

At first really sorry for asking a stupid question. Is it necessary to generate API key to use Google Direction API in my Android Application. How to generate Google Direction API key? Link of any documentation is preferred. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly There is no such thing in this world as a stupid question.

Secondly [go through this documentation you will find what you need](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#api_key)

EDIT VERSION :
Follow these steps.

[open this link](https://console.developers.google.com/)

1. Create a test project.
   2.click API&auth on left menu
   3.click credential
   4.Create new key on the public API access section . Then create a key.

or esle use this key which i  just generated for a sample project.

AIzaSyDZOj1QSw4MM4RzPdUEeNTLEhlntcyfMqw

Comment: I have gone through the documentation. But I am unable to understand the 3 no. point at API Key section which says- "Once the service has been activated, your API key is available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Directions API applications use the Key for server apps. " Can you plz explain it?

Comment: @NadiaAkter follow the steps

Comment: In the 3no. point it is suggested that  'Directions API applications use the Key for server apps'.  What does it mean? Shall I have to generate a new key pressing the server key, although I need the key for an android application.

Answer (score 0):

Using an API key has the following effect:

- [Enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#api_key)

This means, the usage of the api on all devices your app is installed on, is summed together.

If you do not use the API key, the usage is per IP-address. So the limits of the API apply per device.

On a server you have to ability to cache (or use other techniques) to minimize calls. But on a device (IMHO) this ability is limited.

In my apps, I use the Direction API without API-key, so I do not bump into usage limits.

BTW: you can get an API key using the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).